# Реализация платежей через СБП в мобильном приложении

Tags: android, ios, react-native, платежи

Есть задача - организовать оплату в приложении через СБП (Система быстрых платежей)
Есть ли у кого примеры, как это сделать?
В частности, интересует вопрос перехода в установленное банковское приложение - каким образом и с какими параметрами его вызывать?

Comment: А если приложений несколько. В какое откроется в первую очередь?

Comment: Не знаю :) Не проверял

Answer (score 5):

Все оказалось очень просто :)

Мы используем шлюз (Paymaster).

В приложении формируется запрос на оплату, шлюз на основе запроса создает платеж в НСПК с указными реквизитами, после этого, в ответ, мы получаем ссылку на оплату данного платежа и служебную информацию о статусе обработки запроса.

Ответ содержит PaymentUrl вида https://qr.nspk.ru/AD10004F7SM1QOR38T1RNP592HT1U2MC?type=02&bank=100000000054&sum=4000&cur=RUB&crc=0B61

Эту ссылку нужно открыть в базовом браузере телефона.

Если на телефоне будет найдено поддерживаемое приложение для оплаты, оно автоматические запустится.
Если приложение не будет найдено и запущено, плательщик останется на посадочной странице НСПК.